# iOS 10 tap home to use

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, accessibility

I dislike pressing the home button.

How can I make it so that a tap equals a press?
I have it for unlocking the phone (iPhone SE) so it should be possible elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open settings and navigate to

Settings > General > Accessibility > Home Button

Toggle "Rest Finger to Open".

---

For every other situation it is not possible to perform Home Button actions without pressing it.

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you. It's a pity that it does not work elsewhere.